# AngularJS view doesn't wait for $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I have the following...

```
$scope.products = dataService.getJsonData();
console.log($scope.products);
```

and in my dataservice I have the following

```
.service('dataService', function ($http) {

        this.getJsonData = function () {
            return $http.get('path/to/json/products.json').then(function (response) {

                // don't send back everything....
                var productData = response.data;
                console.log(productData);
                return productData;

            });

        };
```

and in my view I have the following...

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">

    Name: {{ product.name }} <br>
    Price: {{ product.price }}
    <hr>
</div>
```

in my rendered view the repeat is showing only 3 items (products is an array of 15 objects). When looking at the console the repeat in the view or products is made of `Object { then=function(), catch=function(), finally=function()}` but the log from the dataservice is out putting the desired object array. I don't understand why the output isn't waiting for the returned data, I thought this was asynchronous? How can I make the view wait for the dataservice without using a `$timeout`. Has anyone else had this problem? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE ***

From a bit of googling I'm pretty sure I need to add a resolve to my $routeProvider, the `$routeProvider` currently looks like so:

```
.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve:{
        // i need to put something here...
      }
  })
```

Comment: Do I need to add a resolve to my $routeProvider perhaps?

Comment: I think i usually add a callback to getJSONData to update $scope, instead of returning data

Comment: No, what you need is $apply. I fixed your code in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `dataService.getJsonData()` it doesnt return the data that the $http.get returns, it returns a promise that will be fulfilled with the data in the future. I would recommend you to read up on promises. You can read about the angular implementation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

As I mentioned, the function returns a promise that will be fulfilled, so you need to set the data in the scope when the promise is fulfilled. Change your controller to this:

```
dataService.getJsonData().then(function (products) {
    $scope.products = products
})
```

Answer (score 2):

hmm not sure if it will help, because angular is async but try adding this to your controller before using the data.

```
dataService.getJsonData().success(function (response){
  $scope.products = response
})
```

Answer (score 1):

With $resource it is a bit easier, like this:

```
dataService.factory('getJsonData', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('path/to/json/products.json');
  }
]);
```

The other parts are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The actual update is happening in a callback, so you need to wrap it in $apply. Because it's happening in a service, you must use $rootscope

```
.service('dataService', function ($http,$rootScope) {

    this.getJsonData = function () {

        return $http.get('path/to/json/products.json').then(function (response) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                // don't send back everything....
                var productData = response.data;
                console.log(productData);
                return productData;

            })
        });     
    };
```

From the angular [promises docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

> // since this fn executes async in a future turn of the event loop, we need to wrap
>   our code into an $apply call so that the model changes are properly
>   observed.

**Edit:** As OdeToCode pointed out, this is really not needed. The reason is that what http.get returns is an Angular promise, which is already doing an $apply internally on the .then() callbacks.

Comment: Well, the $apply in the promises docs is only needed because it is using a setTimeout. What Mike needs is just a call to .then.